# Tags in Search Columns

Tags: profile, custom-search, tags

I wanted to include the tags field in a search profile, so they can be shown in the list of search results. But it is not possible because the option "column in search results" is not available with tags. 
When our volunteers work with telephon lists it would be useful to see the tags...

Comment: To clarify, could you please specify the step by step procedures you are using to get to the stage you're at.